# Projection Method in Hubbard model

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body

This is a question from Altland and Simons book "Condensed Matter Field Theory".

In the second exercise on page 64, the book claims that if we define $\hat P_s, \hat P_d$ to be the operators that project onto the singly and doubly occupied subspaces respectively, then at half-filling the following equality holds

$\hat P_s \hat H_t \hat P_s = 0$ and $\hat P_d \hat H_t \hat P_d =0$,

where $\hat H_t$ is the hopping term in the Hubbard model. I am having trouble to see why the second equality is true. In the doubly occupied subspace, it is not guaranteed that the hopping will produce only singly occupied states. Do I have to write out the projection operator in terms of creation and annihilation operators and directly calculate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is a **two-site** problem, so the many-body Hilbert space is finite (and actually just four). Therefore one can simply express all the operators in terms of $4\times 4$ matrices. Let us order the many-body basis states as $|s_1\rangle=a_{1\uparrow}^\dagger a_{2\downarrow}^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$, $|s_2\rangle=a_{2\uparrow}^\dagger a_{1\downarrow}^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$, $|d_1\rangle=a_{1\uparrow}^\dagger a_{1\downarrow}^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$, $|d_2\rangle=a_{2\uparrow}^\dagger a_{2\downarrow}^\dagger|\Omega\rangle$. Then the hopping term $H_t=-t\sum_{\sigma=\uparrow,\downarrow}a_{1\sigma}^\dagger a_{2\sigma}+h.c.$ is represented as
$$H_t=\left[\begin{matrix}
 0 & 0 &-t&-t\\
 0 & 0 & t& t\\
-t & t & 0& 0\\
-t & t & 0& 0
\end{matrix}\right]$$
Obviously, hopping only connects singly  occupied subspaces to doubly occupied subspaces, and vice versa. The projection operators also have matrix representations,
$$P_s=\left[\begin{matrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right], \quad 
P_d=\left[\begin{matrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$$
Just by matrix multiplication, it can be verified that $P_s^2=P_d^2=1$, $P_sP_d=0$, and $H_t=P_sH_tP_d+P_dH_tP_s$, as well as $P_sH_tP_s=P_dH_tP_d=0$. These are useful results for the following deductions in the book.

Comment: I think the book is implementing the perturbation theory to deal with the extended system, as stated on page 63: "Instead, to gain some intuition for the extended system, we will effect a perturbation theory..."

Comment: @SlipStream Yes, but to the second order perturbation in (t/U), one only need to consider two sites. All the electrons on the other sites are just by-standing and do nothing.

Comment: @ Everett You Thank you so much for keeping up with my question. Could you go into a little bit about details as to why to the second order perturbation in (t/U), one only needs to consider two sites? There is just something missing in my understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: @SlipStream Second order means the electron is only allowed to hop twice. For the first t, the electron hops to one nearest site, and for the second t, the electron has no choice but to hop back to its original site, otherwise the electron will not end up with the single occupied configuration, and hence not contributing to the low-energy theory. So this only involves two sites.

Comment: @EverettYou I think the second order is not restricted to the two-site system because the second order in $t$ is due to the elimination of the first order terms by an appropriate canonical transformation ($H'=e^{-tO}He^{tO}$, where $O$ is chosen such that $H_t=t[O,H_u]$). but I still don't know why this kind of transformation can be done. it is somehow related to the fact that the system is two-sited? thanks